# Can't delete .dat file, because it is open in OpenJDK platform binary

Tags: java

I'm building a javaFX application and having problems with deleting a file once it is opened inside Java.

I have a method:

```
public static void deleteByID(int ID)
    // Creating tempFile
    File tempFile = new File("kiekotTemp.dat");
    File kiekot = new File("kiekot.dat");  // Original file

    // Opening file and going through kiekot.dat
    try (Scanner fi = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(kiekot));
         PrintStream fo = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile, true)))
    {
        // Skipt the first line and copy it to destination file
        fo.printf(fi.nextLine() + "\n");
        while ( fi.hasNext() ) {
            // For the sake of simplicity, we just copy the contents
            String s = fi.nextLine();
            fo.printf(s + "\n");
        }
        
        // End session
        fi.close();
        fo.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("File won't open: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    // Delete the original file and rename the tempFile to match the original kiekot.dat
    kiekot.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(kiekot);
}
```

First run it works fine, but second run it can't delete the "kiekot.dat" file for some reason. When trying manually, it says "File is opened in "OpenJDK platform binary". How can I close the file so I can delete it?'

### What I've tried so far:

I added print statement at the end of `try` to make sure we don't catch any errors. Also, I added some if-statements in so we can see when file is deleted and renamed

```
public static void deleteByID(int ID)
    // Creating tempFile
    File tempFile = new File("kiekotTemp.dat");
    File kiekot = new File("kiekot.dat");  // Original file

    // Opening file and going through kiekot.dat
    try (Scanner fi = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(kiekot));
         PrintStream fo = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile, true)))
    {
        // Skipt the first line and copy it to destination file
        fo.printf(fi.nextLine() + "\n");
        while ( fi.hasNext() ) {
            // For the sake of simplicity, we just copy the contents
            String s = fi.nextLine();
            fo.printf(s + "\n");
        }
        
        System.out.println("We made it to here without errors");
 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println("File won't open: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    // Delete the original file and rename the tempFile to match the original kiekot.dat
        if ( kiekot.delete() ) System.out.println("Successfully deleted the file");
        else  System.out.println("Couldn't delete the file");

        if ( tempFile.renameTo(kiekot) ) System.out.println("Successfully renamed the file");
        else  System.out.println("Couldn't rename the file");
}
```

This now outputs me this:

```
We made it to here without errors
Successfully deleted the file
Successfully renamed the file
```

2nd time I click the button and the method runs:

```
We made it to here without errors
Couldn't delete the file
Couldn't rename the file
```

Restarting the whole application helps, but I need help to make method that doesn't need the restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to solve this, i need to get some more answers to the runtime:

1.: When pressing your button the second time, does the catch-part of the exception activate ?

2.: Did you ever try to get more debug information ? For that, you could rewrite your program like that:

```
public static void deleteByID(int ID)
   // Creating tempFile
   File tempFile = new File("kiekotTemp.dat");
   File kiekot = new File("kiekot.dat");  // Original file

   // Opening file and going through kiekot.dat
   try (Scanner fi = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(kiekot));
        PrintStream fo = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile, true)))
   {
       // Skipt the first line and copy it to destination file
       fo.printf(fi.nextLine() + "\n");
       while ( fi.hasNext() ) {
           // For the sake of simplicity, we just copy the contents
           String s = fi.nextLine();
           fo.printf(s + "\n");
       }
    
       // End session
       fi.close();
       fo.close();

       kiekot.dat
       kiekot.delete();
       tempFile.renameTo(kiekot);

   } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       System.err.println("File won't open: " + ex.getMessage());
   }catch (Exception ex2){
       ex2.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

3.: If there is already a console output from your error, could you post it in here ?

By the way, i am sorry for the delayed answer, but i think we live in completely different time zones. Hope i can help anyways.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers and comments, I appreciate them. I updated the question with some debugging details.

Comment: No problem , i help where i can. Ok, i see you manually added error outputs, but it is not what you want. You want to see what the IDE tells you as error output ("Stack Trace"), so i would consider trying the example above where everything is inside a try-catch clause.

Comment: Ok, i tried your updated code in my IDE (Eclipse) and it worked out perfectly fine ! So i have another assumption right here. Your GUI maybe has some mistakes. I guess you are using AWT and Swing, so could you just please your entire regarding to the error method in here ? From GUI initialization to button to method.

Comment: No idea what happened but now it works? I wrote other parts of the application and now  miraculously this part works too?? Made this the accepted answer since it gives good details how to debug in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot see the problem directly, but there could be a minor bug source causing it: You are using a try-with-resource statement (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in your try-catch:

```
try (Scanner fi = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(kiekot));
     PrintStream fo = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(tempFile, true)))
{ 
   ....... 

}
```

This special statement ENSURES a delete after the execution finished. But you are closing your streams manually with

```
    // End session
    fi.close();
    fo.close();
```

So the source of your problem may be, that you are "stealing" the close operation from your try-with-resource statement. So just try to delete the part where you manually close your streams. Hope this could help.

Comment: I added them afterwards to try to fix the issue. Deleting them does nothing. I have also tried extracting FileInputStream into its own variable and manually close it, didn't work.

Comment: Is the program fully terminating between your runs ? Or is there something like a loop calling your method multiple times ?

Comment: The program doesnt terminate between calls since its an application that doesnt stop running. It does work when I restart the application but I need help to make the method so I can run it multiple times without restarting the application.

Comment: Ok, then try to add a delay between the calls (250ms for example). This will help windows to actually mark the document as "free to use" again.

Comment: I run it with a click of a button and there are several seconds between calls so it's not that. The problem is that Java is keeping the file open for some reason and so I can't delete the file.